# Persisting record error in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to persist record like in the documentation:

```
  var record = this.store.createRecord('record',{});
            record.set('record_text',this.get('record_text'));
            record.set('record_time', Math.round(new Date()/1000));
            record.save();
```

But I receive error:

```
Error: No model was found for 'content'
    at new Error (<anonymous>)
    at Error.Ember.Error (http://zion-le.work/public/scripts/chat/assets/vendor.js:14061:19)
    at Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://zion-le.work/public/scripts/chat/assets/vendor.js:68689:33)
    at JSONSerializer.extend.extractSingle (http://zion-le.work/public/scripts/chat/assets/vendor.js:61641:28)
    at superWrapper [as extractSingle] (http://zion-le.work/public/scripts/chat/assets/vendor.js:14443:16)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extractSave (http://zion-le.work/public/scripts/chat/assets/vendor.js:61161:21)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extractCreateRecord (http://zion-le.work/public/scripts/chat/assets/vendor.js:61090:21)
    at Ember.Object.extend.extract (http://zion-le.work/public/scripts/chat/assets/vendor.js:61018:37)
    at http://zion-le.work/public/scripts/chat/assets/vendor.js:69380:32
    at invokeCallback (http://zion-le.work/public/scripts/chat/assets/vendor.js:23164:19) vendor.js:16672
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: No model was found for 'content' vendor.js:13224
```

I think it's happened because I execute this code in `consultation` instead `record` controller

Comment: This is most likely a problem with the response from the server, which may be including a root tag of `content`.

Answer (score 0):

When you POST or PUT a record, the server responds with a new copy of the object in question.  Ember will parse this and replace the item in the store with the new copy.  I generally override the `extractArray` and `extractSingle` functions in my adapter.  If it is a general pattern, you can do it in your `ApplicationAdapter`, or if it is specific to your `record` type, you can do it in the `RecordAdapter`.